# Need a query to extract uname and ext_id for specific lastname and firstname

Tags: sql, performance

I have to extract uname (exist in info table) for few lastname and firstname values. Below are the tables having relationships.

Table info:

```
  INFO_ID       NOT NULL NUMBER(19)                        
  UNAME         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)                         
  ISACTIVE       NOT NULL NUMBER(1)                        
  USERFLAG      NUMBER(1)
```

Table adminext;

```
  EXT_ID NOT NULL    NUMBER(19)     
  INFO_ID NOT NULL    NUMBER(19)
```

Table admin;

```
 EXT_ID       NUMBER(19)    
 CONTACT_ID   NUMBER(19)
```

Table contact;

```
  CONTACT_ID   NOT NULL NUMBER(19)    
  LASTNAME     VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)    
  FIRSTNAME    VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
```

Comment: Add sample table data, expected result, and you current query attempt!

Comment: Hi, 
Actually I am confused about joining four tables and need a syntactically correct query definition for this. Plz help

Answer (score 1):

So you need 4 joins :

```
SELECT c.firstname,c.lastname,i.uname
FROM contact c
INNER JOIN admin a
 ON(c.contact_id = a.contact_id)
INNER JOIN adminext ae
 ON(a.ext_id = ae.ext_id)
INNER JOIN info i
 ON(ae.info_id = i.info_id)
```

Next time, try to show some efforts on your own.

Comment: Actually I tried this:
select ext_id, uname from adminext ae, info i, contact c,admin ad
                  where i.info_id= ae.info_id and ae.ext_id=ad.ext_id and
                  ad.contact_id=c.personcontact_id and
                  lastname ='something' and firstname='something'

Comment: This is your answer, if it works for you I'll appreciate an approval.. @Dpanshu